# Best pratice to parse the result ? Use parser in PromptTemplate?

Tags: langchain, py-langchain

The revised text is:

Hello,

The method `apply_and_parse` is deprecated:

```
"The `apply_and_parse` method is deprecated; instead, pass an output parser directly to LLMChain."
```

What is the best practice for parsing the result? Here are the possibilities:

- Add an [output_parser](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/prompts/langchain.prompts.prompt.PromptTemplate.html?highlight=prompttemplate#langchain.prompts.prompt.PromptTemplate.output_parser) to the PromptTemplate. I believe this is the best solution because it allows for easy modifications to the prompt for a specific chain and adjustments to the parser over time.
- Or, add an [output_parser](https://api.python.langchain.com/en/latest/chains/langchain.chains.llm.LLMChain.html?highlight=llmchain#langchain.chains.llm.LLMChain.output_parser) to LLMChain.

Both options are viable.